# Generate XYZ Tiles on Openstreet Map using QGIS or Maperitive getting bad Images

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, xyz

I have already done Generate XYZ Tiles with layout png format using **QGis** only zoom level 14 in 10 days.

All image already done 100% thats showup on **QGis** percentage, but some images become blank or black image.
maybe it was fail when render like bad connection or anything else.

Can i render specific image only that blank image but not 1 by 1.

I dont want wasting time 10 days anymore.

Last i trying another application similiar on zoom 13 with **Maperative**
But the result is same.

[image: QGis Result]

[image: Maperative Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have got trouble with your connection or bandwidth osm same like me.

The only solution is download manually, one by one, from the official site, each image.

**https://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png**

Save that image on your folder z x y structure in your blank tiles.